# Background image wont appear in IE10

Tags: css, cross-browser

My background image in my CCS style sheet will not appear in IE10/safari/firefox/chrome but will appear in EI 8 and lower. 
Just wondering is the HTML code needs to updated or I need to add something to this..

Below is the HTML code I have been using..

```
    body {
    background-image: url("https://linktographicetc.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:#DAE4E5;
```

Comment: There's nothing immediately wrong here (except the missing `}` at the end). You need to show a complete example that shows the problem. Does the network tab of the browsers' dev tools show that the image has loaded?

Comment: Your link to the background image is https. Is your site also https? There might be a protocol issue with a difference there.

Comment: please provide a link/fiddle and/or some more code (note the missing "}" at the end that may be your problem)

Comment: @DiMono, that would also be my first thought, but I think IE has always restricted mixed content by default so it would make no sense for it to work in IE 8 and lower.

Comment: Sidenote: that's not HTML code, it's a CSS ruleset.

Comment: Thanks All, The above CSS ruleset (thank DiMono) works in IE8 and lower, so I know the image path is correct. The rule set does have the "}" at the send also. I have tested the site with just this rule set only, no other instructions and am still having the same issues with it not appearing IN EI10/firefox/chrome etc. So this eliminates the theory of other coding blocking this instruction

Comment: Also here is my exact rule set
<STYLE>
BODY A:link

}

body {
    background-image: url("https://www.eventsinteractive.com/medicalmeetings/images/900BIAirways_1_body_001.jpg");
 background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:#DAE4E5;
    
        }  

</STYLE>

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replace your jpg image path to my own background image. And it works.

Maybe there is other div or HTML elements blocking it? Like other users mentioned, kindly show us the codes examples.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks All, The above CSS ruleset (thank DiMono) works in IE8 and lower, so I know the image path is correct. The rule set does have the "}" at the send also. I have tested the site with just this rule set only, no other instructions and am still having the same issues with it not appearing IN EI10/firefox/chrome etc. So this eliminates the theory of other coding blocking this instruction.